# SQL Backup Error - The Users password must be changed before logging on the first time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup-sqldatabase

I am trying to perform a database backup in SQL Server Management Studio 2008. We do this backup yearly, and have had no issues up until today. The error says

> The user's password must be changed before logging on for the first time.

I have checked the users on the database, and none of the accounts are flagged for a password change. The network location we are backing up to has the shared permissions set to read/write. Please help

[image: Error]

Comment: If its running under a windows authenticated account have you checked the state of the login under active directory users/computers on the domain controller?

Comment: The login for the computer was checked for "The user's password must be changed..." but after unchecking it, the same error message pops up.

Comment: Nope!, Correction, you got it. The account was not flagged, but the network drive i was saving it onto was! Thanks!